# How to use Botdetect Captcha from captcha.com in a React project with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, captcha, botdetect

I want to use botdetect captcha from **captcha.com** in my **React** project. The problem is that we use **Typescript** instead of **JavaScript** and when I tried to create a react component from those famous 3 files my project shows multiple compilation errors:

```
reactjs-captcha.js
captcha-settings.js
captcha-helper.js
```

If we used Javascript instead of Typescript we had no issues. Another problem is that we used Function-based components instaed of class-based Components so **"this"** keyword in those files creates compilation errors.
Also you know that the whole point of using those files as component is that you can call
**getInstance()** method and after that **getCaptchaId()** method.

I read all the documentation but I didn't found any guides how to use it in React project with Typescript and also the sample project on **captcha.com** with typescript returns an angular module which I don't know how to convert it to a React component.